# MAX of a varchar column using HQL

Tags: sql, casting, hql, max, varchar

I am trying to find the maximum value of a varchar column in mySQL DB using hibernate query language.

This is the query i am trying to do, and this works fine in native SQL:

```
select max(cast(rs.marks as unsigned)) from Results rs;
```

*where column:marks is a varchar*.

Suppose if column marks (where all the values are saved as texts) has the following rows:

```
65
75
82
41
```

Then the query should return me a unique result "82".
But when i wrote the same in HQL, it doesn't work. Can anyone please help me out by telling me how to write this in Hibernate?

Console says:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node:org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.AggregateNode
[AGGREGATE] AggregateNode: 'max'
[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'cast' {originalText=cast}
[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
[DOT] DotNode: 'results0_.marks_'
{propertyName=marks,dereferenceType=4,propertyPath=marks,path={synthetic-alias}.marks,tableAlias=results0_,className=com.Results,classAlias=rs}
[IDENT] IdentNode: '{synthetic-alias}' {originalText={synthetic-alias}}
[IDENT] IdentNode: 'marks' {originalText=marks}
[IDENT] IdentNode: 'unsigned' {originalText=unsigned}
```

Answer (score 1):

Came across this question and decided to answer although it's very old.

**First of all** this will suffice to get MAX value

```sql
SELECT MAX(marks) max_value FROM Results;
```

**Secondly** there is no `UNSIGNED` keyword in HSQL. Therefore if the result value needs to be converted to  `INT`

```sql
SELECT CAST(MAX(marks) AS INT) max_value FROM Results;
```